# association mapping when one entity isn't managed by Doctrine

Tags: symfony, associations

I have 2 entities in a one-to-one association.  The first, `Person`, is stored in a MySQL database and handled by Doctrine. The second, `AdUserRecord`, describes an ActiveDirectory user record. It is read-only. It does not need to know about `Person`. Also,  `AdUserRecord` properties should never  be stored in the MySQL db for privacy reasons.

An `AdUserRecord` is retrieved using a service, `AdSearcher`, which can search by `samaccountname` or `objectGUID`. Whenever a search is successful, the service checks to see if there is a corresponding `Person` record and creates one if there is not.  That works fine.

My problem occurs when I start with a `Person` object. Mostly, I don't need to access a `Person`'s `AdUserRecord` so I'd prefer not to query Active Directory unless it's required. That means, I think, that `Person::getAdrecord()` needs to have access to the `AdSearcher` service. Something like this:

```
public function getAdrecord(){
   if($this->adrecord) return $this->adrecord; 

   $searcher = ???; //get AdSearcher service somehow
   $record = $search->getRecordByUserGuid($this->ad_guid);
   if(!$record) throw new \Exception('this person no longer exists');
   
   $this->adrecord = $record;
   return $this->adrecord;
}
```

I've been reading the Symfony docs pretty assiduously, but I'm still stumped.

### Questions

- how do I get a service into an entity? Should it be injected via the constructor, or just where it's needed, in the getter? If it only occurs in the getter, do I have to inject it or is there a way to import it?
- is adding a service to an entity the canonical way of handling these types of situations? Would it be preferable to build an entity manager for `AdUserRecord`s?
- what interfaces do I need to implement if I have to build an entity manager?

`Person` class

```
namespace ACRD\DefaultBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ACRD\DefaultBundle\Entity\AdUserRecord;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Orm\Table(name="person")
 *
 */
class Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="AD_guid", type="string", length=36, unique=true)
     */
    protected $ad_guid;

    /**
     * @var AdUserRecord
     */
    protected $adrecord;

     //usual getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Would [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) help you figure it out?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: I'm not really clear on how that might work in my situation. Part of my issue is that with "normal" Doctrine entities I can define the relationship (e.g. `@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Note", mappedBy="expertise")`) in an annotation. I don't think I can do that with my `AdUserRecord`. Can I?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to make a PersonManager and then do $adRecord = $personManager->findAdRecord($person);  That way you don't have to inject services into entities which is frowned on.  Just inject adSearcher into PersonManager.

Comment: @Cerad: is there some documentation on building an entity manager? I couldn't find it.

Comment: It for some reason made a lot of sense when I read this documentation after seeing your question. It doesn't really anymore...

Comment: An entity manager is nothing more than a service. You could take a look at the `UserManager` from the `FosUserBundle` ([found here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php)) and see how they handled things.

Comment: Since AdUserRecord comes out of a active directory database then I don't see any sense at all in trying to make a doctrine 2 entity manager for it.  You already have your AdSearcher service.  Just need to wrap something around it to pull out whatever you need from the person entity and search for it.

Comment: @Cerad, ok so if I have a PersonManager, which is essentially a wrapper for my AdSearcher service, how do I make the PersonManager available from inside `Person`. I have a feeling this is a dumb question, but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: You don't. You make it available from the Person repository.

Comment: As @cheesemacfly says, you don't.  If you really really really want to inject adSearch into a Person entity then I suppose you could listen for the postLoad event.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events But we are both recommending that you look up the ad record from outside the entity when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Doctrine's [`postLoad` event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload) is the best solution.

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/ActiveDirectorySubscriber.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Model\AdAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
// for doctrine 2.4: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware

class ActiveDirectorySubscriber extends ContainerAware implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postLoad',
        );
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!($entity instanceof AdAwareInterface)) {
            return:
        }

        $adSearcher = $this->getContainer()->get('acme_demo.ad_searcher');

        if ($adPerson = $adSearcher->find($entity->getAdGuid())) {
            $entity->setAdPerson($adPerson);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You also mentioned that most of the time you don't need to use the active directory stuff. Before optimizing I highly suggest you actually measure how much of a performance impact there is. If, however, you do notice a performance problem, consider using a proxy object to mitigate the `AdPerson` searching right to the point where you actually need something from it.

```
public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if (!($entity instanceof AdAwareInterface)) {
        return:
    }

    $adSearcher = $this->getContainer()->get('acme_demo.ad_searcher');

    $entity->setAdPerson(new AdPersonProxy($adSearcher));
}
```

The `AdPersonProxy` would basically extend from your `AdPerson` class, wrap each and every public method with a call to load the actual `AdPerson` object and then act as a facade between the two. Consider the following implications before you start coding though:

- it adds complexity to your codebase (the more code, the more there is to maintain);
- it will be a pain to debug - for example you might get an exception inside your 
  template that will leave you scratching your head for a long time (been there,
  done that);

---

The bottom line is that in theory services should (mostly) not be injected inside entities.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your third question:

EntityManagers implement `Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager` - have a look at [the interface on github](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.php).

Further:

a somewhat clean implementation would be similar to the Document<->Entity mapping  (called *references*) provided by [gedmo/doctrine-extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions).

Take a glimpse at the documentation to see how it works [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/references.md) and [here](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/reference_integrity.md).

If that's what you want start diving into the code of the [ReferenceListener](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/Gedmo/References) :)